# Getting the error "Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-pose-estimation) tf implementation of OpenPose model for my project.

From the `models/graph/mobilenet_thin` directory, I'm trying to use the `graph.pb` file by loading it in tensorflow with the
`tf.saved_model.load()` function but as I load the model, I get this warning:

```
Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
```

and because of this, I'm not able to use the `model.predict()` function later in the code.

How can I resolve this issue?

PS: I only have the `.pb` file, not the `vaiables` folder

Comment: This error seems to appear because, you are trying to load the frozen graph (.pb) that is trained with TF 1.x by using TF 2.x. Use same version of Tensorflow for training and loading. And also use full path which means absolute path while loading the frozen graph. Thanks!